# Calculating (experimental) probability of head toss

Tags: python, probability

I want to calculate the experimental probability of heads in coin toss by generating 0s or 1s randomly and assign 'h' for 0 and 't' for 1 to n. The number of flips is 100.

```
import random

array_ht = []

flip_count = 0

while flip_count != 100:
    n = random.randint(0,1)
    if n == 0:
        n = "h"
    elif n == 1:
        n = "t"
    flip_count += 1
    array_ht.append(n)

for x in array_ht:
    h_count = 0
    if x == "h":
        h_count += 1

    print(h_count + "%")
```

The for loop looks through every object of array_ht and if it finds an "h", it adds 1 to the number of head flips. But the code isn't working and just prints "1% 0% 1% 0% 0% ..."

What should actually happen is for example if sequence generated was '0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1' then array_ht = [h,t,t,h,h,h,t,t,t] and probability to be printed is (4/9*100=) 44.444444%.

Actually we don't need to assign 'h' or 't' to n, we can just look for number of 0s but earlier I had wanted to print array_ht also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? This calculates the probality of both `h` and `t` in `%` percentage format.

**EXPLANATION:**

```
import random

tosses = []

# Getting A List With 100, 0s and 1s in it
for i in range(100):
    tosses.append(random.randint(0, 1))

# Indexing Every 0 for a `h` and every 1 for a `t`
for i in range(len(tosses)):
    if tosses[i] == 0:
        tosses[i] = "h"
    else:
        tosses[i] = "t"

# Getting Count Of How Many Times Heads Or Tails Was In The List
freq_h = tosses.count('h')
freq_t = tosses.count('t')


# Calculating The Probablity (freq/total_outcomes) (x100 optional if want to calculate in percentage use x100)
prob_h = (freq_h/len(tosses))*100
prob_t = (freq_t/len(tosses))*100

# Adding A `%` sign to the numbers and round them up
percent_h = str(round(prob_h)) + "%"
percent_t = str(round(prob_t)) + "%"

# The Final Result
print("Probablity Heads:", percent_h)
print("Probablity Tails:", percent_t)
```

**EDIT:** A Much Shortened Version Of The Previous Solution(Quick And Dirty)

```
import random
tosses = []
for i in range(100):
    tosses.append(random.randint(0, 1))
for i in range(len(tosses)):
    if tosses[i] == 0:
        tosses[i] = "h"
    else:
        tosses[i] = "t" 

print("Probablity Heads:", str(round((tosses.count('h')/len(tosses))*100)) + "%")
print("Probablity Tails:", str(round((tosses.count('t')/len(tosses))*100)) + "%")
```

Comment: If needed i can shorten this snippet

Comment: Wow, what a code monster when it can actually be done in 3 lines ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is printing `1% 0% 1% 1%` is because, you placed the `print` statement and `h_count` variable inside your for loop, as a result it gets reinitialized every time you iterate over `array_ht`

```
for x in array_ht:
    h_count = 0
    if x == "h":
        h_count += 1

    print(h_count + "%")
```

so if you do a dry run of your program, here is what it does:

take an element from `array_ht` then initialize `h_count` as 0
if the element = "h", it adds 1 to your `h_count`

then it prints the `h_count`
one iteration is over, go back to start,

take the next element in `array_ht` and re-initializes `h_count` as 0
and then again the same thing

here is a version I made:

```
import random

def toss(num):
    array = [random.randint(0,1) for x in range(num)]
    return array.count(0), array.count(1)


outcomes = toss(1000)
heads = outcomes[0]
tails = outcomes[1]

print(f"Probability of Heads: {heads/sum(outcomes)*100}%")
print(f"Probability of Tails: {tails/sum(outcomes)*100}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution of your problem would be to move `h_count = 0` out of the for loop. But aside of that, your whole code can be simplified:

```py
import random

tosses = ["ht"[random.randint(0, 1)] for i in range(100)] # we can use string indexing to convert "h" and "t" to 0 an 1, respectively.

print(f"{(tosses.count('h') / len(tosses)) * 100}%")
```